# how i can assign ids to svg elements? (to raphaeljs bars)

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, graphael

How i can assign ids to raphaeljs bars in g.raphael barchart and how to access them after

```
var r = Raphael("holder", 600, 500);
var data=[1,3,4,5];
var chart = r.g.barchart(30, 30, 350, 250, [data], {stacked: true, type: "soft"});
for (var i = 0; i < chart.bars[0].length; i++) {
      var bar = chart.bars[0][i];
      if (bar.value >= 7) {
                bar.attr("fill", "#bf2f2f");
                bar.attr("stroke", "#bf2f2f");
                bar.attr("id","id-"+i);   //this doesn't work
                bar.id="id-"+i;           //this also doesn't work
                //applied as per raphaeljs documentatoion 
                //[http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.id][1]
                   }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
bar[0].id = "id-"+i;
//or
bar.node.id = "id-"+i;
```

`bar` is a Raphael element.  Its `[0]` and `node` attributes [point to the actual DOM element](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.node).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

`bar.data("id" : +i)`

More here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data